# count between two tables and finding difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have the following code which works. It's comparing two tables that are exactly the same but in two separate databases to ensure they have the same record count.

I was wondering if anyone saw a better way of achieving the below?

```
Declare @count1 int
Declare @count2 int

select @count1 = count(*) from database1.dbo.table1

select @count2 = count(*) from database2.dbo.table1

if @count1 <> @count2
begin
   insert into log table saying counts don't matc
end
```

Comment: Do you just want the count difference or you want to get the difference in Data?

Comment: would you please explain the business/requirement! then we would help better. maybe it's batter to give some hand of triggerz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no much better way. You can just do it without variables:

```
if (select count(*) from database1.dbo.table1) <> (select count(*) from database2.dbo.table1)
begin
   insert into log table saying counts don't matc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know where the differences are you can use this to find the missing records in database 2

```
SELECT *
FROM database1.dbo.table1 D1
LEFT JOIN database2.dbo.table2 D2
ON D1.id = D2.id
WHERE D2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, but it needs to be on the count only.